# File::deleteDirectory('path') does not remove the directory

Tags: php, laravel, directory, filesystems

I'm trying to remove a folder with images in it.

here is my method for removing the file

```
public function deleteCar($id) {
    $car = Car::find($id);
    $carImages = carImage::where('car_id', $id);

    foreach ($carImages as $image) {
        //Just for testing purposes.
        $image->car_image_path = '/uploads/cars/32/exampleImage.png';

        $pathWords = explode('/', $image->car_image_path);
        $path = $pathWords[0] . '/' . $pathWords[1] . '/' . $pathWords[2] . '/' . $pathWords[3];
        File::deleteDirectory($path);
        $image->delete();
    }

    $car->delete();

    return response()->json(['error' => false, 'data' => $id]);
}
```

What I want to accomplish is to remove the folder and then the model with the correct car_id. That is passed.

The folder does not get removed and neither does the image model.

Comment: Best thing to do is to check if all your variables are what you expect them to be with dd() or var_dump(). My guess is one of them is wrong (either $carImages, $car or $path)

Comment: Where do I see the result from the dd or dump? I’m using xampp

Comment: The wierd thing is that the car i getting deleted

Comment: Add `dd($carImages)` underneath `$carImages = carImage::where('car_id', $id);` .You will see it on the screen when you call the function (unless it's with Ajax). The car is deleted, cause you do `$car->delete();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `public_path` to delete directory:

```
File::deleteDirectory(public_path('uploads/cars/32'));
```

The method will return `true` if it succeeds, `false` if it fails.
Hope it helps

Comment: It was this and also that i needed to add ->get() on the request for car_image modell. Thanks!